# Matplotlib: try to remove axis, but plt.axis('off') turn all figure transparent, why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use plt.axis('off') to remove axis, but when I add this code, it turn all figure transparent,
the code run no problem but have axis without plt.axis('off').

here is the code

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def plot_net(line, dot, name = "test.png"):
    mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5), frameon = False)
    axiss = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

    axiss.set_aspect('equal', adjustable = 'datalim')
    plt.axis('off')

    axiss.scatter(dot[:, 0], dot[:, 1], color = 'red', s = 4)
    axiss.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], 'r.', ls = '-', color = '#0063ba', markersize = 2)

    plt.savefig(name, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0, dpi = 200)
    plt.close()

a = np.random.rand(4, 2)
b = np.random.rand(4, 2)

plot_net(a, b, name = "test2.png")
```

the result without plt.axis('off')
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fPNQ.png)

the result with plt.axis('off')
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7m3E.png)

Comment: Can you try using `savefig` with `pad_inches` equal to something other than 0, say `0.0001`?

Comment: @DavidG it work but the background turn to transparent, and it seems like I can't change the color

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the visibility to false instead of using "off":

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def plot_net(line, dot, name = "test.png"):
    mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5), frameon = False)
    axiss = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])

    axiss.set_aspect('equal', adjustable = 'datalim')

    axiss.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    axiss.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

    axiss.scatter(dot[:, 0], dot[:, 1], color = 'red', s = 4)
    axiss.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], 'r.', ls = '-', color = '#0063ba', markersize = 2)

    plt.savefig(name, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0, dpi = 200)
    plt.close()

a = np.random.rand(4, 2)
b = np.random.rand(4, 2)

plot_net(a, b, name = "c:/temp/test2.png")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, set_visible(False) did hide the axis, but is there a reason why axis('off') turn everything transparent?

Comment: Yes, because it also hides the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code on https://repl.it/repls/DentalRunnyBlockchain#test.png

and it worksfine so axis off does what you want to realize

Comment: yes, and it works same as axis('off') :(,  thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it's related with your definition of "axiss".
if you bypass it it works:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

def plot_net(line, dot, name = "test.png"):
    mpl.rcParams['agg.path.chunksize'] = 10000

    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5), frameon = False)

    plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', adjustable = 'datalim')

    plt.scatter(dot[:, 0], dot[:, 1], color = 'red', s = 4)
    plt.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], 'r.', ls = '-', color = '#0063ba', markersize = 2)

    plt.axis('off')

    plt.savefig(name, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0, dpi = 200)
    plt.close()

a = np.random.rand(4, 2)
b = np.random.rand(4, 2)

plot_net(a, b)
```

Comment: it kinda work, but it will turn the background to transparent, and seems like I can't change the background anymore, thanks for the reply.